# Bootstrap collapse not working properly when using element attributes in combination with javascript collapse method

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using [Bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) to create a step-by-step process where the user in the first accordion has two options. If the first option is chosen, the first accordion should collapse and the second should open. If the second option is chosen, the first should collapse and the third should open. For this I'm using onclick events for the buttons and the `collapse` method.

Currently using the code from the Bootstrap accordion example as in the link above.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button id="btnOne" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12">
        First option
        </button>
        <button id="btnTwo" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12">
        Second option
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Second panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Third panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added click events for the buttons, as below, to show and hide the collapsibles.

```
$('#btnOne').on('click', function() {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
});
$('#btnTwo').on('click', function() {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseThree').collapse('show');
});
```

**Now to the problem:** Before clicking any of the buttons the default accordion functionality (from using the attributes on the html element), (e.g. clicking the title of one accordion opens it and closes others) but there seems to be a problem when using the javascript methods in combination with the functionality using the attributes.

**Example 1:** If I open the second accordion, without pressing the button in the first accordion, and then opens the first accordion to press the "First option" button to open the second accordion it is not opened. The javascript `$('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')` does not seem to be triggered.

**Example 2:** If I instead click on the first option directly, after the page has loaded, the second accordion opens properly. Now the problem instead is when opening the first accordion by clicking the header it won't collapse the second accordion.

Is it possible to use the javascript methods in combination with the `data-toggle="collapse"` and the other attributes and benefit from the functionality of both?

Or, do I need to manually (by triggering the javascript methods) show and collapse the accordions, to get rid of the problem?

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96qfkx8L/1/) to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the simplest solution is to collapse all open collapsibles in the panel-group using the `show.bs.collapse` event exposed by Bootstrap's collapse class.

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion').find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```